# Replace the words in a list with the position of each word

Tags: python

```
Sentence = input("type in sentence:").split()
```

The above stores the individual words in the input into a list. But now how do I replace each word in `Sentence` with the position of that word?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the string to its index using the map and index function.

```
Sentence = str(input("Type in the sentence here:")).split(" ")
indexed_sentence = list(map(lambda x: Sentence.index(x), Sentence))
```

You may also do:

```
indexed_sentence = [Sentence.index(x) for x in Sentence]
```

or

```
indexed_sentence = []
for x in Sentence:
    indexed_sentence.append(Sentence.index(x))
```

or

```
indexed_sentence = []
for x in Sentence:
    for count in range(len(Sentence)):
        if x == Sentence[count]:
            indexed_sentence.append(count + 1)
            break
```

Comment: lambda is basically a nameless function that you can throw away after using it one time.

Comment: I'm not understanding your requirements. Could you elaborate? Are you saying you can't use str.index()?

Comment: What are the numbers separated by in the string?

Comment: I'm still unsure what you want the count variable used for. The solutions provided output your requirements. What component of the solution do you need to be replaced?

Comment: I reimplemented the index function using the inner for loop. The for loop increments the count variable behind the scenes. I add one to accommodate the indexing starting at 0. See the updated solution.

Answer (score -1):

Just do this:

```
Sentence = [x for x in range(len(Sentence))]
```

Comment: If this is your answer, why not just do Sentence = list(range(len(Sentence)))?

Comment: @mattsap: Because `range` returns a generator in 3.x python. Perhaps `list(range(len(Sentence)))`.

Comment: @mattsap Because the OP wants to replace the words with the position which obviously means to be in a list.

Comment: Aiman, right. @MarkyPython, You are just reassigning the sentence variable. list(range(len(Sentence))) also creates a list and does the same.

Comment: I am using 3.4 as well, you will have to provide more information about the error so I can know what is the problem.

Comment: You need to print out the sentance, `print(Sentence)`